# SAMD21: how to set PWM using TCC?

Tags: c++, arm, embedded, pwm, samd21

I'm programming a SAMD21 and I need PWM.

When I chose pin with F function TCC0 output:
PA22 - TCC0/WO[4]
PA23 - TCC0/WO[5]

I successfully configured TCC0 base counter:

```
// enable clock for TCC0 - disable clock masking
PM->APBCMASK.reg |= PM_APBCMASK_TCC0;

// set GCLK1 as source to the TCC0 counter
GCLK->CLKCTRL.reg = GCLK_CLKCTRL_GEN(1) | GCLK_CLKCTRL_CLKEN | GCLK_CLKCTRL_ID(0x1A);
while(!SYSCTRL->PCLKSR.bit.DFLLRDY);

// set counter
TCC0->CTRLA.reg |= TCC_CTRLA_PRESCALER_DIV64; // setting prescaler
TCC0->WAVE.reg |=  TCC_WAVE_WAVEGEN_NPWM | TCC_WAVE_POL0;
while (TCC0->SYNCBUSY.bit.WAVE);

// set TOP (PER) value of counter - frequency
TCC0->CTRLA.bit.RESOLUTION = 0;
TCC0->PER.reg = 48'000'000 / (100 * 64) - 1; // Fpwm = Fglk / (PRESC(PER+1))  --> PER = Fglk / (Fpwm * PRESC) - 1
while (TCC0->SYNCBUSY.bit.PER);
```

But the problem was how to configure the compare channels - the SAMD21 has only 4 compare channels (CC) but I want output to WO[4] and WO[5].

How can I connect given compare channels to WO[x] pins?

EDIT:

I have also configured pins for mutiplexing (not sure if correctly):

```
PORT->Group[0].PINCFG->reg |= (1 << PIN_PA22) | (1 << PIN_PA23);
PORT->Group[0].PMUX->bit.PMUXE = (0x5 << (PIN_PA22/2));
PORT->Group[0].PMUX->bit.PMUXO = (0x5 << (PIN_PA23/2 + 1));
```

Comment: I haven't used PWM on these parts, but I'm almost certain that the problem is that you need to write to the PMUX register for the given pin. There's a magic number, that corresponds to a magic letter, that corresponds to the peripheral you want to route there. And yeah it is quite obscure. Check the part called I/O multiplexing in the manual and see which magic numbers and letters you need.

Comment: If you are using ASF bloatware libs, then something along the lines of `PORT->Group[0].PMUX[PIN_PA22/2].reg = PORT_PMUX_PMUXE(x)`, where x is the magic number from the routing table in the manual.

Comment: Forgot to mention it but I allready did it (not sure if correctly thou): ```PORT->Group[0].PINCFG->reg |= (1 << PIN_PA22) | (1 << PIN_PA23);
    PORT->Group[0].PMUX->bit.PMUXE = (0x5 << (PIN_PA22/2));
    PORT->Group[0].PMUX->bit.PMUXO = (0x5 << (PIN_PA23/2 + 1));
```

Comment: Looks weird. `PORT->Group[0].PMUX->bit.PMUXE` is the upper nibble of 4 bits in a 8 bit register, `PMUXO` is the lower nibble. So why the strange shift by `PIN_PA22/2`, shouldn't it just be a shift by 4 in the `PMUXE` case and no shift at all in the `PMUXO` case? If the magic number 5 is the one you need to write. That shift is what the bloatware macros `PORT_PMUX_PMUXE` and `PORT_PMUX_PMUXO` do. Shift by 4 or 0 respectively.

Comment: (And yeah, this register hardware layout deserves some manner of worst design award)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [PWM library](https://github.com/ocrdu/Arduino_SAMD21_turbo_PWM) you can re-use code from; it comes with a table (under "extras") with timers, output pins, output channels, pin multiplexers etc.

The library was written (by me) for SAMD21G-based Arduinos, but all the mappings and code you need are there, and it may help you in your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: `PORT->Group[0].PMUX` is an array! Which decays into a pointer to the first element if you do `PMUX->bit`, so it compiles, but it is wrong. You are setting the first element instead of the pin `PIN_PA22/2` that you are interested in.

The routing `PMUX` register type in the ASF register map looks like this:

```
typedef union {
  struct {
    uint8_t  PMUXE:4;          /*!< bit:  0.. 3  Peripheral Multiplexing for Even-Numbered Pin */
    uint8_t  PMUXO:4;          /*!< bit:  4.. 7  Peripheral Multiplexing for Odd-Numbered Pin */
  } bit;                       /*!< Structure used for bit  access                  */
  uint8_t reg;                 /*!< Type      used for register access              */
} PORT_PMUX_Type;
```

Meaning you can either write to the 8 bit `reg` or the 4 bit `bit` nibbles. You seem to do the latter. If `0x05` is the "magic number" obtained by the manual, you should write this one both to the "even" and the "odd" nibble. That is:

```
PORT->Group[0].PMUX[PIN_PA22/2].bit.PMUXE = (0x5 << 4);
PORT->Group[0].PMUX[PIN_PA22/2].bit.PMUXO = (0x5 << 0);
```

Or if you will, you can alternatively use pointless ASF bloatware macros to hide away "scary" bitwise logic:

```
PORT->Group[0].PMUX[PIN_PA22/2].reg = PORT_PMUX_PMUXE(0x5) | PORT_PMUX_PMUXO(0x5);
```

If you don't get these right, there will be no activity on the pin at all.

Comment: Btw type punning through unions is not allowed in C++, so you can't use this register map reliably when compiling as C++. I'd advise switching to C for hardware-related programming, for this reason alone any many other reasons as well.

Comment: What do you mean by type punning through unions? Sry for newbie question

Comment: @EFK It means that C allows you to write to one member of the union like `bit.PMUXE` and then later access another member of the same union like `reg`. This isn't allowed in C++, it is undefined behavior there. Lots of PC programmers carry weight in the C++ committee and so that language is turning increasingly useless for embedded systems with each revision of the standard...